# Binary diff file

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, files, binary, diff

`bsdiff` uses `max(17*n,9*n+m)` bytes of memory (where n is the size of the old file and m is the size of the new file) according to http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/

Is there a lighter (in terms of memory) alternative for me given the following circumstances?

- The changes will only take place when I am aware
- I have `sudo` power
- The file is between 1 GiB and 10 GiB

---

My use:

- Copy file from external drive to `tmpfs`
- *Many*, many writes will take place on the file in the `tmpfs` (I do not know where in the large **binary** the writes will take place)
- Make the file in the external drive the same as the one in the `tmpfs`

---

Right now, I have two solutions:

- Run `bsdiff` to get a patch (and apply the patch to the file in an external drive) - this does not work for me; the computer I am using does not have enough memory for running `bsdiff` on this large file.
- Copy the whole file over to the external drive. This works, but uses up the flash erase (remember, I am working with large files) and takes a long time (redundant copying).

Note: I am able to have both the "original copy" (from the external drive) and the "working copy" (same as the one from the external drive, but will be making many changes to this file) in the `tmpfs`.

Would monitoring changes as they are made to the file and building a patch from that be possible (and also more memory efficient)? If so, how?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/125376/how-do-i-compare-binary-files-in-linux; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118403/how-to-compare-binary-files-to-check-if-they-are-the-same

Comment: if all you need is to know if they are different compare md5 hashes? I would assume that is going to be quicker than a diff (but I will let you test that ;-) )

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for your suggestion, but I need to apply the changes back to the "master copy" after use

Comment: Ok. The next method I would choose would be to redirect those patches to a backup file and then execute those patches on the original. But that might will require code to be inserted into your software. That we can not help with since we can not look into your software. It could be as simple as a  `cat {patch} >> /dir/to/patchfile.txt`  ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind I might be misunderstanding your suggestion (or maybe you're misinterpreting my question?). I'm trying to get the difference (generate a patch) between the master copy and the used version. I am able to apply the patch to the master copy once I get the patch. My question is how I can generate such a patch on large binary files without using excessive memory.

Comment: Oh I understand but know of no such method. Hence I suggested another approach: why not catch the patches when they are executed onto the temp file so you can repeat the process on the original?

Comment: @Rinzwind So basically "monitoring changes as they are made to the file and building a patch from that"? If so, how would I go about doing that? (by the way, I am not applying patches from `diff` to the used version. The changes are made by external software I have no control over)